# Calculus - Derivative help

Tags: calculus

I'm sure this problem is much simpler then I think, but how do I derivative this function: [image]

Thank you,

Yaniv

Comment: Our function is $x^{-1}-x^{-2}+2$. Now apply standard formulas. Recall in particular that the derivative of $x^k$ with respect to $x$, where $k$ is a constant, is $kx^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You may just use

> $$
> \frac1x=x^{-1}\qquad \qquad  \frac1{x^2}=x^{-2}
> $$

and

> $$
> (x^{\alpha})'=\alpha \times x^{\alpha-1}
> $$

which may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\left( f(x)+g(x)\right)'=f'(x)+g'(x)$ and some derivative rules to get: $$f'(x)=\left(x^{-1}\right)'-\left(x^{-2}\right)'+(2)'=-x^{-2}+2x^{-3}=-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x^3}$$